# Routing with match() doesn't work in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, match

I have a main page with job listings.

Once a user clicks on a specfic job listing, a new site route e.g. ***"homepage.com/jobs/12345"*** shall open the description of the clicked job.

All of the information for the jobs are stored in an array. Each job is stored in an object.

**My Question:** How can I show the description of the clicked job (description key from clicked job item) on a new route like in example URL above?

**An item in the array looks like this:**

```
  {
    "id": "12345",
    "position": "Marketing Manager",
    "company": "Apple",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum",
    "date": "2018-11-27T23:11:27Z"
  },
```

**Routing in App.js looks like this:**

```
<Router>
        <React.Fragment>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/"
            render={() => (
              <Home jobs={filteredJobs} searchChange={this.onSearchChange} />
            )}
          />
          <Route
            path="/jobs/:id"
            render={({ match }) => (
              <div>
                <Description
                  description={
                    this.state.jobs.find(job => job.id === match.params.id)
                      .description
                  }
                />
              </div>
            )}
          />
        </React.Fragment>
      </Router>
```

**Home.js looks like this:**

```
render() {
    const { jobs, searchChange } = this.props
return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <Navigation />
    <Filter searchChange={searchChange} />
    <Categories searchChange={searchChange} />
    {jobs.map((job, index) => (
      <JobCard
        key={index}
        id={job.id}
        position={job.position}
        company={job.company}
        image={job.image}
        date={job.date}
      />
    ))}
  </React.Fragment>
)}
```

**JobCard.js looks like this:**

```
render() {
    const { company, date, position, image, id } = this.props
    return (
      <Router>
        <Card data-cy="JobCard" to={`/jobs/${id}`}>
          <Image src={image} />
          <Position>{position}</Position>
          <Company>{company}</Company>
          <Date>
            <Moment format="D MMM">{date}</Moment>
          </Date>
        </Card>
      </Router>
    )
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: whats the error or problem with your current code? It seems like you correctly passed the description to the new route component now all you need to do is render it

Comment: Well once I click the new route is displayed in the adress field. But the new route does not open. Weirdly, if I reload, then it opens and displays the description correctly

Comment: I see. It might help to wrap your `Description` component in `withRouter(...)` so that it gets notified of paths changes to trigger a rerender

Comment: Can you explain how that would work? I have read into it but don't know where to put it

Comment: Import withRouter from react-router, then in your Description component export it like `export default withRouter(Description)`

Answer (score 0):

We are using react-router and redux for fetching data.

Our way in routes:

```
            <Route path="jobs/:id" component={ Job }/>
```

in Job Component you will need to fetch your data:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({ job }) => ({ job });

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    actions: bindActionCreators({
        fetchJob
    }, dispatch)
}
);

@connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
export default class Job extends Component {

// your code here

}
```

Comment: I am not using Redux, so I think in my case it will be different?

Comment: you could try to get in Job Component window.location.pathname and extract id from it and filter for this job?